# deserializing Json data which contain an array in c#

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization

I have a problem for deserializing another list inside Json message.
My code work fine for read data like Project, Ref, Latitude ...
I tried both method too : list and array.

For example my JSON message:

```
[{
    "Project":"example", 
    "Ref":"001BC50C70000A21", 
    "Latitude":43.643166, 
    "Longitude":1.454769, 
    "ParkList": [{
        "Id":"001BC50C70000A21P1", 
        "State":1, 
        "DateTime":"2018-02-15T08:07:18.987Z"
    }, {
        "Id":"001BC50C70000A21P2",
        "State":1,
        "DateTime":"2018-02-15T08:11:41.824Z"
    }]
}]
```

My class:

```
[DataContract]
public class KMessage
{
    private string ProjectField;
    private string RefField;
    private float LatitudeField;
    private float LongitudeField;
    public List<TParkList> ParkList { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Project
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ProjectField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ProjectField = value;
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Ref
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RefField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RefField = value;
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public float Latitude
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LatitudeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.LatitudeField = value;
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public float Longitude
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LongitudeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.LongitudeField = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class TParkList
{
    private string IdField;
    private int StateField;
    private string DateTimeField;

    [DataMember]
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.IdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.IdField = value;
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public int State
    {
        get
        {
            return this.StateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.StateField = value;
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string DateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this.DateTimeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.DateTimeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And the main code for test. So the list is empty for "kmsg.ParkList":

```
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface IKService
    {
        [DataContractFormat] 
        [OperationContract] 
        [WebInvoke(
             Method = "POST",
             BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
             RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             UriTemplate = "/state")]
        void Service(Stream KStream); 
    }

    public class KService : IKService
    {
        public void Service(Stream KStream)
        {
            try
            {
                if (KStream == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("WebService message is NULL");
                }

                else
                {
                    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<KMessage>));
                    var obj = (List<KMessage>)serializer.ReadObject(KStream);

                    foreach (KMessage kmsg in obj)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Project", kmsg.Project);
                        foreach (var pklist in kmsg.ParkList)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("List - Id", pklist.Id.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it, this might help.. Implementation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UqxAyR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function provided by Visual studio which convert your json into a model class

**Goto: Edit -> Paste special -> Paste JSON as Class**

Model class created by this feature will solve your problem

I used this feature and created model class for you.

```
        //Use respective attributes 
        public class KMessage
        {
            public string Project { get; set; }
            public string Ref { get; set; }
            public float Latitude { get; set; }
            public float Longitude { get; set; }
            //I guess here is the problem, instead of array you can use list
            public Parklist[] ParkList { get; set; } 
        }

        public class Parklist
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public int State { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        }
```

I guess you are missing something, while deserialization, here is how you can deserialize your json string. I am using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) library.

```
string jsonString = "[{\"Project\":\"example\", \"Ref\":\"001BC50C70000A21\", \"Latitude\":43.643166, \"Longitude\":1.454769, \"ParkList\": [{\"Id\":\"001BC50C70000A21P1\", \"State\":1, \"DateTime\":\"2018-02-15T08:07:18.987Z\"}, {\"Id\":\"001BC50C70000A21P2\",\"State\":1,\"DateTime\":\"2018-02-15T08:11:41.824Z\"}]}]";

//You used [square brackets] at first, so we need to deserialize with list
List<KMessage> kMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KMessage>>(jsonString);
foreach (Parklist item in kMsg[0].ParkList)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Id: " + item.Id + " State: " + item.State + " DateTime: " + item.DateTime);
     }
```

---

```
Output:

Id: 001BC50C70000A21P1 State: 1 DateTime: 2/15/2018 8:07:18 AM
Id: 001BC50C70000A21P2 State: 1 DateTime: 2/15/2018 8:11:41 AM
```

---

Proof of concept: [.net Fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UqxAyR)

Comment: Thanks for showing me a nice feature that I did not know.

Comment: I start my class construction by this method. I have try again and the problem is the same. I just add [DataContract] and [DataMember] (without, code don't enter in the first foreach) and they work again with same model class, but the problem is the same.

Comment: In the second foreach, program go in the catch because parklist is empty

Comment: I'm using you library Newtonsoft.Json. I try first your code inside my first foreach, so when I post Json message, I enter in you code for test ParkList Class for beginning. But they doesn't work too. jsonString is ok and kMsg is null for type System.Collections.Generic.List<KMessage>

Comment: I don't understand why, in the first foreach loop, I have each field with data and ParkList array is empty. So When I try to deserialize object, i deserialize null object.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want to achieve, but hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I progresse now because you code works fine in my project. In this line : List<KMessage> kMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KMessage>>(jsonString); , how can I change jsonString by KStream in my datacontrat ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare your list as a member of a data contract in `KMessage`. 
That means it isn't serializable.

Try to add it to your class `KMessage`.

```
[DataMember]
public List<TParkList> ParkList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ParkList;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ParkList = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I try to declare this list in KMessage, but doesn't work too. My kmsg.ParkList is again an empty array.

Comment: @PouLpeX I updated my answer and for your json string code is also working fine. please check it

Comment: As shown that's going to cause an infinite recursion.  But `[DataMember]` works just fine on auto-implemented properties so there's no need to switch to explicit implementation.